# Alternative for "tone-deaf"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, political-correctness

*Tone-deaf*, in the figurative sense, refers to saying something without considering how it will land with your audience:

*Wishing your vegetarian colleagues in Mumbai "Happy Turkey Day!" came off as a little **tone-deaf**.*

However, in these politically correct times, the expression may cause offence to people with actual hearing loss and is apparently best avoided.  Is there a good alternative that would work in the phrase above?  (Words or short phrases are both fine.)

A couple of synonym sites I consulted were not very helpful: [synonym.com](https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/tone-deaf) offers "deaf" as a synonym (uh, no), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tone-deaf) offers "out of touch" (better, but not quite?) and most other major thesauruses don't seem to have it.

And a final vain plea: let's please try to avoid the discussion of whether this expression actually is or "should" be considered non-PC.

Comment: At the risk of offending pianos and whatnot, how about *off-key*?

Comment: "tone-deaf" is nothing to do with hearing loss. It's to do with being unable to differentiate musical notes, while still having normal hearing.

Comment: So saying "tone deaf" is tone deaf?

Comment: The point of the expression is more missing the underlying meaning of your own words, rather than missing how it will land with your audience. The end result, though, is that your audience understands what you yourself did not intend -- but the harm is done.

Comment: Please don't remove useful tags

Comment: A minor instance of foot-in-mouth disease.

Comment: Tone-deaf is used for people that don't understand musical forms and cannot reproduce an exact frequency when singing. It’s an ability that their brain does not have, much like for colorblind people. (I am colorblind myself, so no offense to anyone.) One typical application of it would be in karaoke.

Comment: @Mitch: "Ham-handed" is about clumsiness, maladroitness. It's not about the size of the hands but what you do with them.

Comment: Don't confuse "tone-deaf" with "stone-deaf". As others have pointed out the former has to do with differentiating musical notes. The latter means being as deaf as a stone is.

Comment: @Iman Tone deafness is generally used colloquially to refer to someone with bad pitch, rather than someone with a legitimate inability to tell if two pitches are the same or different. Most of these people could likely improve with training. That's a bit different from colorblindness, which is typically a result of the *eye* lacking color-sensing cones, rather than anything related to the *brain*. Colorblind people simply do not have the necessary apparatus to even *sense* color differences, unlike tone-deaf people, who can sense differences but not *recognize* them.

Comment: @NuclearWang I have discovered that I am unable to memorize colours, and I was pointing at this in my comment and forgot that this is a personal discovery and no one is aware of this fact. Assume that you show me two colours that I can not say which is named green and which is yellow, then you introduce me those colours and say this for example is green and the other is a yellow. I can remeber it for couple of hours and discriminate them, but if you come tommorow and ask me which was which, I can not tell you, cause I can not remember the colours. :( this could be subject for PhD thesis!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s **insensitive**. See for example these headlines:

- [A culturally insensitive nursing textbook illustrates the pickle medicine is in](https://qz.com/1112865/uproar-over-a-culturally-insensitive-nursing-textbook-illustrates-the-pickle-medicine-is-in/)
- [How Being Polite Can Be Insensitive to People with Disabilities](http://www.mauracullen.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/How-Being-Polite-Can-Be-Insensitive-to-People-with-Disabilities.pdf)

Comment: To me, "insensitive" has a nuance of being possibly intentional, whereas "tone-deaf" makes it clear the perpetrator is just oblivious?

Comment: And interestingly, that 2nd link says "hearing impaired" is inappropriate, while "(person who is) deaf" is fine.

Comment: I don't think "insensitive" carries the connotations of being intentional: the meaning of being insensitive is that you're unaware or unthinking of causing offence. "Insensitive" fits in situations where you should have been aware, but that's different to being intentional.

Answer (score 7):

You could say it was a “faux pas“ or a “gaffe” because it was a socially awkward blunder. You could describe the remark as “gauche” or, a bit less harshly, as “clumsy.”

If you’re particularly looking to describe the person, not the action, you could call them “careless,” “thoughtless,” “inconsiderate,” or “graceless.”

Answer (score 3):

"Out of tune" is a possible alternative, one which isn't quite as negative as "insensitive".

Answer (score 3):

[Tactless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tactless) also is from music but doesn't carry an offensive overtone.

> having no tact; unaware or intentionally inconsiderate of someone else's feelings

Answer (score 1):

**Obtuse** may work, as it can refer to insensitivity as well as the lack of wit or smarts of someone who demonstrates such insensitivity. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obtuse):

> 2a : lacking sharpness or quickness of sensibility or intellect : insensitive, stupid
>
> > He is too *obtuse* to take a hint.

So to include that in your present example, *obtuse* would describe someone not realizing how "Happy Turkey Day" does not fit what a vegetarian who doesn't even celebrate Thanksgiving might know:

> Wishing your vegetarian colleagues in Mumbai "Happy Turkey Day!" came off as a little **obtuse**.

Comment: ["How can you be so obtuse?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7wREOySaxU)

Answer (score -3):

You could say:

*Wishing your vegetarian colleagues in Mumbai "Happy Turkey Day!" is not very **au fait**.*

> **au fait**
>
> To be familiar with or know something
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/au-fait)